# compiling cpp with CL.exe from Visual Studio Express under Win 8.1x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cl.exe

I downloaded the latest Visual Studio to be able to use its command line compiler  cl.exe. 
When I do:

```
"<full path to cl.exe>" /I"<full path to my include folder>" "<full path to my .cpp>" /Fe"<Full path to the output .exe>"
```

I get the error saying that mspdb110.dll is missing.
I did add its folder to the system path, and I don't get that problem if I run my command console "as administrator".

I see other posts suggesting that I use "Developer Command Prompt" (and run it as administrator).

Is there no work around to use my regular command prompt to build my program specifying the necessary options for cl.exe directly? For one thing, I am not able to "Drag and drop" the .cpp into the console window, automatically getting its full path there.

Comment: You can do it, but it can be somewhat painful (especially when it comes time to do an upgrade, and you need to undo everything you did). You can look through `vcvars.bat` to see what it does, then edit your environment do do the same separately.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Oh well. Things were so simple when I used BCC32 (borland) as my compiler. But I am getting the sense I need to switch to something that's still being developed, hence this VS thing.